# 3d real time tracking stability

Tags: graphics, 3d, computational-geometry, augmented-reality, vision

Im trying to get good hand tracking without any sdk, only with math and openGL.

First with kinect v1 I get the 3d depth points and hence the convex hull (CH) of this set of points. I found that the CH its geometrically different at every frame, then i tried the point set registration technique for a point matching and preserve the form of the CH but im still get undesired results (i.e vibrations of about +- 3,4 degrees) Can you recommend a computer vision algorithm or approach for this problem?.

Answer (score 1):

Im trying to get good hand tracking without any sdk, only with math and openGL.

First with kinect v1 I get the 3d depth points and hence the convex hull (CH) of this set of points. I found that the CH its geometrically different at every frame, then i tried the point set registration technique for a point matching and preserve the for of the CH but im still get the undesired results (i.e vibrations of about +- 3,4 degrees) Can you recommend a computer vision algorithm or approach for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use KinFu library from PCL package, it is implementing "kinect fusion" algorithm